# Can't serve a base64 ttf font in NGINX

Tags: nginx

Below there's my configuration, and even if it seems appropriately configurated for ttf fonts, it doesn't get served (file [here, from fullcalendar](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/packages/core/src/common/icons/_icons.scss))

```
[...]
http {
    [...]
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    types {
        application/x-font-ttf ttf;
        font/ttf ttf;
        font/otf otf;
        font/woff woff;
        font/woff2 woff2;
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot;
    }
[...]
}
server {
        proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://use.fontawesome.com; frame-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://via.placeholder.com data: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://use.fontawesome.com data: ; font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://use.fontawesome.com data: ; form-action 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests 'always'; object-src 'none'";
}
[...]
```

Comment: For any errors with nginx, logs should be your first thing in checklist. If Nginx doesn't gets the access/error logs, you should check from browser debug console whether browser even invokes this request to server and gets any response.

Comment: Uhm.. there's no trace in the logs of a request for the base64 ttf...... Maybe there's a problem somewhere else? On the Angular dev server (ng serve) it works, I don't know where could the problem be.. Thank you for the tip though.

Comment: Check if browser actually invoking that request to server..? Since it's not showing up any traces in logs, I doubt the request not even invokes from browser.

Comment: On local it does! It's when I serve the webapp with NGINX that the request doesn't happen :-/